# Faceook Graph API not returning email of other user accounts except the administrators

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

The URL Im pointing to is:

```
const res = await fetch(
          `https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/me?locale=en_US&fields=email,picture.width(720).height(720)&access_token=${accessToken}`
        )
```

I am using this endpoint to get the user information but the email is not returned even the version used in the URL is the latest **v12.0**. Interestingly the email of only the administrator account is been returned.

I have assigned **Advanced Access** to both email & public_profile.

[image]

Is something missing here?
Thanking in advance :)

Comment: Did you ask the users for the relevant permission, when they logged in ...?

Comment: I don't think so. Will this be done through the dashboard? or is it shown automatically to the user in the web popup?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the reason why some of the accounts were not returning the *email key* in the object was that they do not have any primary email setup for their Facebook account inside the ***General Account Settings***.

> **The users were using their *phone numbers* or *username* to log in on Facebook**.

That's why when they were logging in to my application, the Facebook Graph API couldn't get the email from their accounts, and ultimately I couldn't get their email addresses in the response object.